# Documentation of file objects __exit__() method

Tags: python

Looking into the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) of the `with` statement in python:

> 6. The context manager’s `__exit__()` method is invoked.

I was wondering what exactly happens if I do

```
with open("foo","w") as f:
    pass
```

Judging from the documentation and `f.closed` evaluating to True suggests, that the `__exit__()` seems to be somewhat equivalent to a `close()`. But I was wondering if there is any more detail to be found about the actual behaviour of the `__exit__()` function. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase is one place it’s referenced: “IOBase is also a context manager and therefore supports the with statement. In this example, file is closed after the with statement’s suite is finished—even if an exception occurs”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a more specific answer, `open` returns a subclass of `_io._IOBase` (depending on options). The `__exit__` method is implemented in C in [`iobase.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f320be77ffb73e3b9e7fc98c37b8df3975d84b40/Modules/_io/iobase.c) with the code

```
static PyObject *
iobase_exit(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    return PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(self, _PyIO_str_close, NULL);
}
```

which you can see, just calls the objects `close` "method".

Answer (score 2):

Anything can be used as a context manager - it just has to provide it's own `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. See [PEP343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) for all the details on how `with` and context managers work.

In the case of `open` this is actually a call to `io.TextIOBase` class under the hood. This is implemented mostly in C, but there's a fallback python implementation (`_pyio.py`) which contains the following code, which confirms that it just calls `close()`

```
### Context manager ###

def __enter__(self):  # That's a forward reference
    """Context management protocol.  Returns self (an instance of IOBase)."""
    self._checkClosed()
    return self

def __exit__(self, *args):
    """Context management protocol.  Calls close()"""
    self.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the context manager itself; the point is that a context manager can determine what to do when it exits.

In the case of `open`, yes what it does is close the file; but other context managers are free to do whatever they like. A database connection manager might commit or rollback the cursor before closing the connection, for example; or a temporary file manager might delete the tempfiles.